# remote root login through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I have 2 different servers which im accessing remotely through ssh. i am currently writing a bash script that will move some archives from server A to server B on a weekly basis via crontab. script will run from server A. naturally at some point it needs to login to server B. i set up RSA keys and they are working fine (ran ssh user@B from A and it doesn't ask for a password anymore, i get right in).

Problem is the user@B i have doesn't have write permissions (ssh root login is disabled on B). in order to gain root access i need to login with my regular user@B then type su - and enter root password, which i have and it works when doing so from B directly.

My question is: Can i program the script to do this (type su - and enter the root password) automatically after logging into B as the regular user@B through RSA? and then proceed to scp the files in the destination folder on B?

thanks

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://superuser.com. Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Thanks and Good luck.

Comment: Can you just change permissions on the destination folder, allowing your user to place files there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with sudo.

By configuring sudo (using visudo as documented in "man 5 sudoers") can you enable an unpriviledged user to run certain commands as root without requiring a password.

Then you can run "ssh hostname sudo sometask"

So for your scenario, first copy over the files to the destination with "scp", then run a script with elevated priviledges on the target host using sudo.

If you want to do it both in one go what you can do is run tar locally, pipe it into `ssh hostB sudo tar -C directory xf -` so a tar running as root on hostB will be able to unpack it with root permissions:

```
tar cf - directory | ssh hostB sudo tar -C directory xf -#
```

(untested)

Comment: so basically i can enable my user@B to run scp without having root privileges.. alright, thanks for answering, i'll look into it.

Comment: no, scp will run as the user on the remote machine. If you want to create the files with elevated privileged directly, use the "tar" solution with "sudo" that I added to the solution.